# Find $\alpha,\beta,K$ $\frac{a_{n+1}+\alpha}{a_{n+1}+\beta}=K \left(\frac{a_{n}+\alpha}{a_{n}+\beta}\right) $

Tags: sequences-and-series

I would appreciate if somebody could help me with the following problem

Q: Find $\alpha,\beta,K(\alpha,\beta,K\in\mathbb{R})$ such that

if $a_{n+1}=\frac{4a_n+8}{a_n+6}, a_1=4(n=1,2,\cdots)$   then   $\frac{a_{n+1}+\alpha}{a_{n+1}+\beta}=K \left(\frac{a_{n}+\alpha}{a_{n}+\beta}\right) $

Answer (score 1):

Since
\begin{eqnarray}
\frac{a_{n+1}+\alpha}{a_{n+1}+\beta}&=&\frac{2\frac{a_n+4}{a_n+6}+\alpha}{2\frac{a_n+4}{a_n+6}+\beta}=\frac{\frac{a_n+4}{a_n+6}+\frac{\alpha}{2}}{\frac{a_n+4}{a_n+6}+\frac{\beta}{2}}=\frac{a_n+4+\frac{\alpha}{2}(a_n+6)}{a_n+4+\frac{\beta}{2}(a_n+6)}\\
&=&\frac{\frac{\alpha+2}{2}a_n+3\alpha+4}{\frac{\beta+2}{2}a_n+3\beta+4}=\frac{\alpha+2}{\beta+2}\cdot\frac{a_n+\frac{6\alpha+8}{\alpha+2}}{a_n+\frac{6\beta+8}{\beta+2}},
\end{eqnarray}
we have
$$
K=\frac{\alpha+2}{\beta+2},\quad \frac{6\alpha+8}{\alpha+2}=\alpha,\quad \frac{6\beta+8}{\beta+2}=\beta,
$$
i.e.
$$
\alpha,\beta \in \{2+\sqrt{3},2-\sqrt{3}\},\quad K=\frac{\alpha+2}{\beta+2}.
$$
Thus
$$
K=
\begin{cases}
1 &\mbox{ if } \alpha=\beta=2\pm\sqrt{3}\\
\frac{19+2\sqrt{3}}{13} &\mbox{ if } (\alpha,\beta)=(2+\sqrt{3},2-\sqrt{3})\\
\frac{19-2\sqrt{3}}{13} &\mbox{ if } (\alpha,\beta)=(2-\sqrt{3},2+\sqrt{3})
\end{cases}.
$$

Answer (score 0):

$\alpha =\beta =-\frac{8}{5} $

and $K=\frac{12}{5}$

By substitution You can get it easily , just put $a_n+1$ in Given expression and equate both side for $$\alpha$$and $$\beta$$

Answer (score 0):

Changing the notation for fewer keystrokes,
we want
$\frac{a_{n+1}+u}{a_{n+1}+v}=K \left(\frac{a_{n}+u}{a_{n}+v}\right)$
when
$a_{n+1}=\frac{pa_n+q}{a_n+r}$.

Blindly substituting for $a_{n+1}$
and writing $a$ for $a_n$,
$u$ for $\alpha$,
$v$ for $\beta$,
and $p, q, r$ for $4, 8, 6$,
we want to find $u, v, $ and $K$
so that
$\frac{\frac{pa+q}{a+r}+u}{\frac{pa+q}{a+r}+v}=K \left(\frac{a+u}{a+v}\right)$
or
$\frac{pa+q+u(a+r)}{pa+q+v(a+r)}=K \left(\frac{a+u}{a+v}\right)$
or
$\frac{(p+u)a+q+ur}{(p+v)a+q+vr}=K \left(\frac{a+u}{a+v}\right)$.

Cross-multiplying,
$((p+u)a+q+ur)(a+v) = K((p+v)a+q+vr)(a+u)$
or
$$ a^2(p+u)+a(v(p+u)+q+ur)+v(q+ur) 
= Ka^2(p+v)+Ka(u(p+v)+u+vr)+Ku(q+vr)
$$
or
$$0=a^2((p+u)-K(p+v))+a(v(p+u)+q+ur-K(u(p+v)+u+vr))+v(q+ur)-Ku(q+vr)
$$

For this to be true,
the coefficients of $a^2$,
$a$, and the constant term
must be zero.
This gives us three equations for
$u, v, K$:
$$(p+u)-K(p+v) = 0,$$
$$v(p+u)+q+ur-K(u(p+v)+u+vr) = 0,$$
and
$$v(q+ur)-Ku(q+vr)=0.$$

These are unfortunately nonlinear,
so
I'll stop here.